# Icomoon font cut off on right side

Tags: html, css, svg

I use icomoon font on my webpage.

example:

http://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu/o-nas

I mean the zigzag line above/below titles and subtitles.

In my case its cut of on the right side.You can see on the pictures

[photo lenovo  http://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu/scr-chrome-lenovo.jpg](http://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu/scr-chrome-lenovo.jpg)

[photo 2 lenovo  http://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu/scr-chrome-lenovo2.jpg](http://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu/scr-chrome-lenovo2.jpg)

It's work well except on one laptop i've tested: lenovo g5030. The weird thing is that all browsers: Chrome, FF, IE have the same symptom.

I've tried to change px to em, but failed to bring any result. Same: reduce the font size and adding padding.

I met with a similar situation in android system, but the first time I see something like that on desktop browsers.

Do you have any ideas? Maybe it's bug of icomoon bug or my svg file is broken?

I read this post
 [large Iconfont icon cut off on the right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346572/large-iconfont-icon-cut-off-on-the-right-side) 
but it doesn't help me.

Comment: In which situations does it not work?  Just that one laptop?

Comment: Error in the font glyphs or loading of font file? Have you tried using TTF only?

Comment: It was happen just thet one laptop. But Alvin K. solution help.Thanks. Seams that was error inside font file. Now it works like a charm.